# concatenating the empty rows in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have data frame as below

```
Name         ID         Rank
==============================
Jobn        0001        1
Wick        Nan         Nan
John        0101        22
lewis       Nan         Nan
James       0201        12
Bo          Nan         Nan
nd          Nan         Nan
```

Here, I need to merge the names based on the ID and Rank values if its Nan then I have to concat the names in different rows until the values are not Nan.

The output looks like below

```
Name         ID         Rank
==============================
Jobn Wick       0001        1
John lewis      0101        22
James Bo nd     0201        12
```

I tried the following code

```
for rowid in range(len(tableDf)):
    for colid in  range(len(tableDf.columns)):
        if pd.isna(tableDf.iloc[rowid,colid]):
            print(tableDf.iloc[rowid-1,colid])
            #print(type(tableDf.iloc[rowid - 1, colid]))
            if type(tableDf.iloc[rowid - 1, colid]) == str:
                print("got a string nan")
                # tableDf.at[rowid-1,colid] = str(tableDf.iloc[rowid-1,colid]) +   str(tableDf.iloc[rowid,colid])
            else:
                print("got a NON string nan")
                # tableDf.at[rowid - 1, colid] = tableDf.iloc[rowid - 1, colid] + tableDf.iloc[rowid, colid]
```

But I am not able to merge the rows.Any suggestions how to solve this problem?
Note: The column names are not fixed.It may change.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
df['ID'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
name_dict = {i:' '.join(df['Name'].loc[df['ID']==i].values) for i in df['ID'].unique()}
df['Name'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: name_dict[x])
df.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
```

Rather than combining the rows, you can take advantage that only one row per ID has non-null values. What you can then do it forward fill the ID column so the script knows which strings to associate with which IDs. Then, you map the names back to all rows with the IDs. You'll now have many rows with duplicate names, but only one row per name won't have a null value for Rank, so you can drop any rows that have nulls in the column.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html)

```
#df = df.mask(df.eq('Nan'))   #if neccesary
blocks = df[['ID', 'Rank']].notna().all(axis=1).cumsum()
new_df = (df.groupby(blocks, as_index=False)
            .agg({'Name' : ' '.join,
                  'ID' : 'first',
                  'Rank': 'first'}))
print(new_df)
```

---

**Output**

```
          Name    ID Rank
0    Jobn Wick  0001    1
1   John lewis  0101   22
2  James Bo nd  0201   12
```

**Detail**

```
print(blocks)
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    3
dtype: int64
```

**EDIT**

if you have Name column and many others:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Name'])
blocks = df[cols].notna().all(axis=1).cumsum()
new_df = (df.groupby(blocks, as_index=False)
            .agg(dict({'Name': ' '.join}, **dict(zip(cols, ['first']*len(cols))))))
print(new_df)
          Name    ID Rank
0    Jobn Wick  0001    1
1   John lewis  0101   22
2  James Bo nd  0201   12
```

---

Or you can use:

```
cols = df.columns[1:]
blocks = df[cols].notna().all(axis=1).cumsum()
new_df = (df.groupby(blocks, as_index=False)
            .agg(dict({df.columns[0]: ' '.join}, **dict(zip(cols, ['first']*len(cols))))))
print(new_df)
          Name    ID Rank
0    Jobn Wick  0001    1
1   John lewis  0101   22
2  James Bo nd  0201   12
```

Comment: the columns count may change.Here I added only two columns for simplicity purpose,there are around 50 columns I have.

Comment: please check section EDIT, you can use `pd.Index.difference` and set the aggregate dict dinamically

Comment: ```pandas.core.base.SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported```,getting the error.I checked that error,reason in new pandas version named aggregation is the recommended replacement for the deprecated “dict-of-dicts” approach